# How to match a string that starts and ends with the same letter?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression that consists of the characters `{x,y}` but must start and end with the same letter? For example:

- `xyyyxyx`
- `yxyxyxy`

Comment: Will a string of length 0(epsilon) will be included in this regular expression or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This regex works:

```
^([xy])[xy]*\1$|^[xy]$
```

I [tested it on regexr](http://regexr.com?38i6b) with

```
xyyyxyx
yxyxyxy
x
y
xyyyxyy
yxyxyxx
xyzyxx
z
```

and it only matched the first four.

Answer (score 13):

This should work for you:

```
^(x|y).*\1$
```

This regex will match a string that starts and ends with the same letter (as the post title suggests), but does not limit the string to contain only x and y characters.  It will match any strings, starting and ending with the same letters *specified in the parenthesis*.

It will match strings consisting of {x,y} characters, starting and ending with the same letter:
(as the OP specified.)

**xyyyxyx**
**yxyxyxy**
zxyxyxz
xyxyxyy

But it will also match strings with any characters in between (not limited to only x and y):

**xgjyhdtfx**
**yjsaudgty**
xuhgrey
yudgfsx
**yaaay**

Working regex example:

https://regex101.com/r/TER7zI/1

Answer (score 5):

I'm bad with regex but this would work I think

```
^(([x][xy]*[x])|([y][xy]*[y])|[x|y])$
```

Answer (score 2):

The following regex works in sed.

```
^\(.\).*\1$
```

to find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
^([xy])(?:.*?\1)?$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kN0yQ4

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^([xy]|[xy]).*\1$/
```

I've tested that with the following test cases: (It matches the bold ones)

**xyyyxyx**
**yxyxyxy**
x
y
xyyyxyy
yxyxyxx
**xyzyxx**
z

Answer (score 1):

```
^(a).*(a)$|^(b).*(b)$
```

This works. I have tested with:

- aba - true
- abbb -false
- bab - true
- abababa - true
- aba - true
- aaaabbbbbaaa

Explanation:

1st Alternative `^(a).*(a)$`

- ^ asserts position at start of a line

1st Capturing Group (a)

- a matches the character a with index 9710 (6116 or 1418) literally (case sensitive)
- . matches any character (except for line terminators)
- * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

2nd Capturing Group (a)

- a matches the character a with index 9710 (6116 or 1418) literally (case sensitive)
- $ asserts position at the end of a line

2nd Alternative `^(b).*(b)$`

- ^ asserts position at start of a line

3rd Capturing Group (b)

- b matches the character b with index 9810 (6216 or 1428) literally (case sensitive)
- . matches any character (except for line terminators)
- * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

4th Capturing Group (b)

- b matches the character b with index 9810 (6216 or 1428) literally (case sensitive)
- $ asserts position at the end of a line
  Global pattern flags
- g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Answer (score 1):

To correct regex is
^(x).*(x)$|^(y).*(y)$|^([xy])[xy]*\1$|^[xy]$

Here we are matching start and end character with all validations where x and y appears in string.

Answer (score 0):

> This regular expression works for me and gives you more control over
> the start and end value  `^(x|y).*(x|y)$`

```
import re
#Check if the string starts with "x or y" and ends with "x or y":

txt = "xyyyxyx"
x1 = re.search("^(x|y).*(x|y)$", txt)

txt2 = "yxyxyxy"
x2 = re.search("^(x|y).*(x|y)$", txt2)

if x1:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
# YES! We have a match!

if x2:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
# YES! We have a match!
```

`^(x|y)`  <<-- this means start with x or y, you can replace x and y values or add more

`.*` <<-- zero or more characters in between the start and end value

`(x|y)$` <<-- same as start but end with x or y values we can replace x or y or add new values.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

`\b(x\w*)?x\b`

[Live Demo](https://regexr.com/6vu2u)

[image: sample code]